# php session_id() deletes previous data in $_SESSION array

Tags: php, session, sessionid

according to php.net in order to change the session id in the cookie then the line session_id($id) has to come before the line session_start(). my question is when I first started a session and assigned values to the $_session array and then in another script I changed the session id. why was the data that I assigned has been deleted??

first script - starting a session and assigning values to the session array:

```
<?php

session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION["username"] = "joshmathews" ;
$_SESSION["name"] = "josh" ;

?>
```

second script- changing the session id but failing to access the data from the first script:

```
<?php

session_id(200) ;
session_start();
echo "<br>Username = " . $_SESSION["username"];
echo "<br> name= " . $_SESSION["name"] ;
echo "<br>" . session_id() ;
?>
```

Comment: session_id(..) receives strings, not a number, I am not sure what happens if you provide a number there

Comment: alternative use session_regenerate_id(TRUE) intested of session_id('strId');

Comment: writing the id in string doesn't have an effect. I tried it and it was the same.

Answer (score 0):

1.if you want to update the session_id() value then you should **session_regenerate_id()**.

2.if you want to completely delete the session details, then use **session_destroy()**